# Object ID assignment in Python (for Sets)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

I recently discovered this interesting behavior of Python when it doesn't generate unique object IDs after instantiating a couple of new `Set` objects.

Let me demonstrate:

```
Python 3.9.9 (main, Nov 21 2021, 03:23:42)
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> id(set())
4349096672
>>> id(set())
4349096448
>>> id(set())
4349096672
>>> id(set())
4349096448
>>> id(set())
4349096672
```

Despite calling set() multiple times, there are only two unique object IDs available:

1. 4349096**672**
2. 4349096**448**

Comment: I assume this is some sort of resource-saving by not instantiating new empty objects when there are two already available and not in use.

Comment: An object's ID is only guaranteed to remain stable and unique _during its lifetime_. You release the sets immediately after creating them, so they get garbage collected and the memory is reused for the next set that gets created.

Comment: This explains it. Thank you!